# Replace elements from one list to other according one pattern

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists:

```
 lis1= {{8, 11}, {5, 3}, {1, 9}, {7, 2}, {10, 4}, {12, 6}}
 list2= {{1, "1DD"}, {2, "1CD"}, {3, "2DD"}, {4, "2DC"}, {5, "1DD"},{6, 
 "1CD"}, {7, "2DD"}, {8, "2DC"}, {9, "1DD"}, {10, "1CD"}, {11,"2DD"},{12, "2DC"}}
```

And I need to create a third, replacing elements of `list2` in `list1` according with the first number, so the `out` is:

```
out= {{{8, "2DC"},{11,"2DD"}},{{5, "1DD"},{3, "2DD"}}...}
```

Comment: `Transpose /@ Transpose[{lis1, Replace[lis1, Rule @@@ list2, 2]}]`?

Comment: if the ordering is irrelevant, you can also use `GatherBy[list2, Position[lis1, First[#]][[1, 1]] &]`

Answer (score 3):

I'd make an `Association[]`:

```
assoc = Association[#[[1]] -> # & /@ {{1, "1DD"}, {2, "1CD"}, {3, "2DD"}, {4, "2DC"},
                                      {5, "1DD"}, {6, "1CD"}, {7, "2DD"}, {8, "2DC"},
                                      {9, "1DD"}, {10, "1CD"}, {11, "2DD"}, {12, "2DC"}}]
```

and then

```
Map[assoc, {{8, 11}, {5, 3}, {1, 9}, {7, 2}, {10, 4}, {12, 6}}, {2}]
   {{{8, "2DC"}, {11, "2DD"}}, {{5, "1DD"}, {3, "2DD"}}, {{1, "1DD"}, {9, "1DD"}},
    {{7, "2DD"}, {2, "1CD"}}, {{10, "1CD"}, {4, "2DC"}}, {{12, "2DC"}, {6, "1CD"}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Replace[lis1, # -> {##} & @@@ list2, 2]
```

> {{{8, "2DC"}, {11, "2DD"}}, {{5, "1DD"}, {3, "2DD"}}, {{1, "1DD"}, {9,
>           "1DD"}},
>      {{7, "2DD"}, {2, "1CD"}}, {{10, "1CD"}, {4, "2DC"}}, {{12, "2DC"}, {6, "1CD"}}}